# Analyzing BERT-models -- Using raw output logits or softmax values?

Tags: deep-learning, bert-language-model, transformer-model, softmax, logits

In the description of BERT's output it says:

> Prediction scores of the language modeling head (scores for each vocabulary token before SoftMax).

I have problems in understanding what this output means. My aim is to compare human response data with BERT data in an experiment (fill-mask). I use fill-mask with the option `topk` and I group the predicted fillers by linguistic properties (here, number).  For BERT I can use  either the raw scores (logits) for the predictions or I first normalize them by applying softmax. Comparing the two methods, I find different correlations. So here are my questions:

1. Looking for correlations between BERT responses and human responses, which BERT-output should be used? Raw logits or softmax values?
2. Is it ok to add up raw logits to get a group score?
3. If softmax is used, should it be applied to the logit scores of the single predictions or to the summed group score?

My main problem is that I do not know how to interpret the raw logit scores. Are these probabilities transformed in the log-space? But then, why does the quote above emphasize that the scores are "before Softmax"? Any suggestions what I should read? I know the architecture of BERT and the training procedure.
Thanks!